# Can I integrate TFS with Jira and Zephyr?

Tags: tfs, jira

My company are imposing Jira and Zephyr on us for defect tracking and test management. We're quite happily using TFS 2008 for both these jobs at the moment, but management have never let the fact that something isn't broken stop them from trying to fix it.

Are there any tools/plug-ins that will allow us to synchronise between the remotely hosted repositories and our in-house TFS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too late, but the company might want to look at the new features for bug tracking and manual tests coming in the 2010 release. Nice as Jira is, I doubt it will integrate well with the historical debugger and the ability to include a video of the test, as well as information on the test environment, and have it all be part of the work item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is, as you say, too late, but I appreciate your time.